# onReorder() arguments in Flutter ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter, dart, reorderable-list

I try to create a **reorderable list in Flutter** with the ReorderableListView widget:

```
return ReorderableListView(
    onReorder: (int index, int targetPosition) {
        print(index.toString() + " -> " + targetPosition.toString());
    }
...
```

I can´t find an exact explanation of what the two arguments in onReorder are. I found some "oldIndex", "newIndex" staff - but that doesn´t look like it´s correct.

I´ve build an example with a List with three items. When I drag the items I get the following (for me confusing) results:

```
Position 1 -> Position 2 results in 0 -> 2
Position 1 -> Position 3 results in 0 -> 3
Position 3 -> Position 1 results in 2 -> 1
```

For me, it looks like a mixup of index and position...

Maybe someone has an idea what´s my mistake?

Answer (score 17):

According to the documentation regarding the [ReorderCallback](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ReorderCallback.html), the `oldIndex` and `newIndex` gets passed to the callback.
There's even an example given on how the callback could be used to actually order items in a `List`:

```
final List<MyDataObject> backingList = <MyDataObject>[/* ... */];

void handleReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
  if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
    // removing the item at oldIndex will shorten the list by 1.
    newIndex -= 1;
  }
  final MyDataObject element = backingList.removeAt(oldIndex);
  backingList.insert(newIndex, element);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to implement refreshindicator in re-orderable list view?

Comment: `RefreshIndicator` should work with any `Scrollable` widget, so yes, you should be able to just wrap the reorderable list view in a `RefreshIndicator`.

Comment: Thanks for reply i tried to wrap my re-orderable list view with ```RefreshIndicator``` it's working but, when list don't have minimum data for scroll ```RefreshIndicator``` didn't refresh my re-orderable list.

Answer (score 14):

It's old and new index, but it has problems. There are open issues for that, as you can see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24786).

Here's an example that shows how to use them:

```
onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
  setState(() {
    // These two lines are workarounds for ReorderableListView problems
    if (newIndex > _sampleItems.length) newIndex = _sampleItems.length;
    if (oldIndex < newIndex) newIndex--;

    MyItem item = _sampleItems[oldIndex];
    _sampleItems.remove(item);
    _sampleItems.insert(newIndex, item);
  });
},
```

You can see a demo [here in this snippet](https://gist.github.com/ffeu/e6ab522bdbcdfdfc7056bcc7ff2f67c7).

As per my experience (2019/January), I gave up on the Flutter's ReorderableListView and started using [knopp/flutter_reorderable_list](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_reorderable_list). I even made a [Widget to make that switch easier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53908179/796963), check it out and see if it makes sense to you.

Comment: 2022, the problem is still a thing, fix still works

Answer (score -1):

The onReorder function is written wrong in most tutorials. I think this one I just wrote is working.

```
void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    setState(() {
      newIndex > oldIndex ? (){newIndex--; int row = V755.removeAt(oldIndex);
      V755.insert(newIndex, row);}() : (){int row = V755.removeAt(oldIndex);V755.insert(newIndex, row);}();
    });
}
```

Comment: V755 is a list BTW, sorry